# SELF-REFERENCE AND THE LANGUAGES OF ARITHMETIC

Tags: logic, goedel, predicate-logic, self-reference

Hello can someone explain me exacty how in this fragment of the paper (SELF-REFERENCE AND THE LANGUAGES OF ARITHMETIC, RICHARDG.HECK,JR.):

- (9) Tr(x) ≡∃y(rhs(x,y)∧¬Tr(y)), where rhs(x,y) is a formula representing the relation: y is (Gödel number of) the right-hand side of the biconditional (whose Gödel number is) x. Diagonalization then yields a formula G such that PAs
  (Paeno arithmetic , 's' stands for standard language)

proves:

- (10) G≡[Tr(`G`)≡∃y(rhs(`G`,y)∧¬Tr(y))], where, as usual, `G` abbreviates the numeral denoting the Gödel number of the formula G.

How (10) can be derived from (9) trough Diagonalization?

Comment: See e.g. [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/).

Comment: I don't see how following the steps of the "diagonalization lemma" referenced there takes one from (9) to (10)

Comment: But then G in (10) must be equivalent to (9) , how then in (10) is it equivalent to the right-hand side of the equivalence(10)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See e.g. [Gödel’s Incompleteness Theorems : Diagonalization](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/#DiaSelRef): it is a general result of FOL that :

> Let **A(x)** be an arbitrary formula of the language of **F** with only one free variable. Then a sentence **D** can be mechanically constructed such that
>   **F ⊢ D ≡ A(⌈D⌉)**.

In [Heck's paper](https://academic.oup.com/philmat/article-abstract/15/1/1/1448434?redirectedFrom=PDF), page 2, the author applies this general result to formula (9) above (of system **PA**), which is of "form" **A(x)** [variable **y** is *bound*].

Thus, there is a *sentence* (closed formula) **G** such that : **PA ⊢ G ≡ A(⌈G⌉)**, i.e. a formula **G** such that **PA** proves:

> > **G ≡ [T (⌈G⌉) ≡ ∃y(rhs(⌈G⌉, y)∧¬T (y))]**.

Comment: Thanks, altough this:  G ≡ [T (G) ≡ ∃y(rhs(G, y)∧¬T (y))]. Supposed to be --> G ≡ [T (⌈G⌉) ≡ ∃y(rhs(⌈G⌉,y)∧¬T (y))].